# how to install turnserver on centos 6.5 32bit

Tags: centos, software-installation

I get the following error while turnserver on centos 6.5 32bit.
How can I solve it?

```
[root@d turnserver-3.2.2.1]# ./install.sh

libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
annot add package libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64.rpm to transaction. Not a compatible architecture: x86_64
Error: Nothing to do
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libevent-1.4.so.2 is needed by (installed) nfs-utils-1:1.2.3-39.el6_5.3.i686
    libevent-1.4.so.2 is needed by (installed) libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.i686
    libevent_core-1.4.so.2 is needed by (installed) libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.i686
    libevent_extra-1.4.so.2 is needed by (installed) libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.i686
    libevent = 1.4.13-4.el6 is needed by (installed) libevent-devel-1.4.13-4.el6.i686
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.10()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libcrypto.so.10(libcrypto.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libssl.so.10()(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
    libssl.so.10(libssl.so.10)(64bit) is needed by libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64
ERROR: cannot install package libevent-2.0.21-2.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

Answer (score 3):

From your output:

> Not a compatible architecture: x86_64

Your options are to download and install a 32-bit version, if that is available.  Or install this version on a 64-bit operating system.

It is sometimes possible to run 32-bit software on a 64-bit processor, but not the opposite.